# Video.JS freezes browser when scrubbing to end of clip (HTML5)

Tags: jquery, html, video, video.js

Ok, so here is my scenario (that isn't working):

1) Load an mp4 clip into video.js & playback (this works great). Start scrubbing using the slider... still works great.

2) Scrub to the very END of the clip. The busy image comes up and spins, and the browser hangs (IE11). ???

This only seems to happen if I scrub to the very end (possibly before the clip is fully loaded?). Scrubbing to any value in between works perfectly fine.

Also, I am not using Flash fallback, this is only HTML5 video.

Any ideas?

NOTE: I just realized that the main video.js website also does this in IE11... (and the browser stays open in the services gathering up memory... loop maybe?).

Thanks!
-Brian

Comment: Do you have a link to where you observe this or is it possible to recreate it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: I would check the video encoding to make sure it's right if there's no errors from anything on your page

Comment: The video.js main site exhibits the behavior for me: http://www.videojs.com/

Just click toward the very end of the slider, then trying clicking back.

This actually hangs my browser and makes VideoJS unusable until I open a new browser instance entirely.

Comment: One more comment... I'm starting to believe this may be IE11 related (not specific to video-js).

http://jsfiddle.net/8rkaL/

If you continue to slide the progress to the end / click on the end, you can end up in the same error state.

Comment: Wow... well, this isn't where I thought the rabbit hole would lead... but this may be an issue with hardware acceleration in IE11 (not sure of previous IE versions). 

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-iewindows8_1/ie-11-crashes-at-end-of-embedded-video-signs-out/b00f82f9-fb8d-487f-b960-1a55925fcc27

(I run with Intel embedded graphics on my laptop when not using the discrete card for 3d apps).

Comment: Just a further comment... the above prevents the overall page freeze, but does not stop the video from getting stopped up. I do believe this is actually a bug with IE11 and HTML5 video though... as I can get similar results with a straight video tag.